# Radius of convergence proof (sequence of series)

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

[image]

In the proof of the theorem, it says if $|z|>R$ then a similar argument proves that there exists a sequence of terms in the series whose absolute value goes to infinity. What does it mean? How should I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\lvert z\rvert>R$, choose $\varepsilon>0$ such that$$(L-\varepsilon)\lvert z\rvert=r>1.$$By the definition of $L$, we have $\lvert a_n\rvert^{1/n}\geqslant L-\varepsilon$ infinitely often. But, when this happens, we have$$\lvert a_n\rvert\lvert z^n\rvert\geqslant\bigl((L-\varepsilon)\lvert z\rvert\bigr)^n=r^n.$$Since $r>1$…

Comment: Thank you, but how do you show the absolute value of the series goes to infinity though...I don’t think we can use the triangular inequality there

Comment: Since $r>1$ (which imples that $\lim_{n\to\infty}r^n=\infty$) and $\lvert a_n\rvert\lvert z^n\rvert\geqslant r^n$ infinitely often,$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^N\lvert a_nz^n\rvert=\infty.$$

Comment: I thought the absolute value of the series means $|\sum_{n=0}^N a_nz^n|$, no?

Comment: like there’s a sequence of $|\sum_{n=0}^{n_m}a_nz^n|$ that goes to infinity as $m$ goes to infinity and $n_m$ goes to infinity

Comment: Whoever wrote that text did not mention “the absolute value of the series”. That person mentioned “a sequence of terms in the series whose absolute value goes to infinity”. And I proved that such a sequence exists.

Comment: @yunadesu . If $|z|>R$ then  infinitely many terms  of the summation have absolute values greater than $1$ so the series cannot converge. It would not be correct to say "Then it goes to infinity".  The sequence of partial sums has a sub-sequence that does, but the whole sequence of partial sums could be almost anything.

Comment: Thank you. How to prove that the sequence of partial sums has a subsequence that goes to infinity, is that a theorem?

Comment: I did not mention the sequence of partial sums. What I wrote was that the sequence $\bigl(\lvert a_nz^n\rvert\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb Z_+}$ has a subsequence whose limit is $\infty$.